# Thoughts on if it's possible to succeed in math @ PhD level w/o natural ability in quant reasoning?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, graduate-school, mathematics

As someone who has a relative deficit in quantitive reasoning (63%ile) vs. verbal (97%ile), but a strong interest in applied math, is it possible to be successful and competitive at the PhD level?

I am committed to putting in the effort, and I want to believe that this is possible - but it is very daunting.

EDIT1:

To flesh out the q: 
I’ve taken Calc 1, Calc 2, Calc 3, Stat/ w Calc & Discrete Math. I got a B+ in the first 2, A in the third and 4th, and B in the 4th. Taking Linear Algebra/Real Analysis and expecting an A or a B. Calc 1&2 and Discrete math were taught at the liberal arts college I went to where I received a BA in the humanities. After my BA in the humanities I pursued ad-hoc post-bac in math so that I’d be able to apply to grad school. Calc III and Stats with Calc were taken at Columbia and LA/RA At Harvard.

I will say, I have improved dramatically since I first began taking math (w/ Calc I & II).

The test I took was WAIS-III full scale IQ test, designed to be taken with no preparation and administered at a world renown  neuropsych facility.

Regarding the GRE, I expect I’d be able to score in a percentile on par with other prospective applicants.

My plan is to apply to a terminal masters, ace that, and the go one to apply to PhD programs.

Lastly, I have significant adhd for which I was unmedicated in undergrad and may but may not account for relative split in grades before and after.

EDIT2:

I'm specifically interested in applied math. I want to pursue it because I find it challenging and interesting and immensely rewarding when I grasp a concept -- and I want to go into a field that helps people.

Comment: I'm not in math, but I've heard on this site that a typical pure math PhD student is expected to easily ace the math GRE. I'm not sure about applied math (or really even what it is, but I digress).

Comment: do the test makers disclose what mathematicians / math students usually get?

Comment: What is your current education level?  Have you taken college level math classes (in actual college, not high school)?  How did you do in those?  I would be hesitant to allow a standardized test to decide my life and career path, and there is nothing wrong with taking a few classes to "test the waters" prior to making a significant commitment.

Comment: Is “quantitative reasoning” assessment anything more than pseudoscience? This is a genuine question (despite, admittedly, scepticism on my part). I know that IQ tests are backed by solid evidence, but this concerns broad correlations to *general* intelligence not, as far as I know, specific (and somewhat arbitrary) subsets.

Comment: Tests don't mean anything.  I mean, ask yourself how motivated you were to do well on that test.  How much effort did you put into understanding the types of questions it was going to ask and why?  All it tells you is that you're probably not that interested in quantitative reasoning tests or the types of problems they throw at you.  But maybe there *are* applied math problems that get you excited, and you'll see your aptitudes change dramatically when you're driven by passion to stay up until 11PM scratching equations onto paper.  If you have that passion, then do it.

Comment: I really like this comment. Thank you.

Comment: I don't have the exact quote, but I remember reading Paul Halmos (perhaps somewhere in his autobiography) where he said that in his experience the verbal score was a better predictor of success in pure mathematics than the mathematics score.

Comment: well that is heartening

Comment: @JohnColeman I've heard several people say things like this, but what was probably meant is that quantitative scores don't carry a lot of useful information since nearly everyone who goes into mathematics does well on quantitative tests.

Comment: Why do you want to pursue graduate studies in math?  I think this is a huge missing piece of your question.  Is it something that you've gotten more interested in the more you learn about it?  If you could add that to your question I think you might get higher quality answers (although @Buffy does somewhat hint at it in theirs).

Comment: I want to pursue it because its challenging and interesting and I want to understand.

Comment: @azorahai It's important to distinguish between the math section of the general GRE and the GRE math subject test, which is significantly more difficult.

Comment: "I want to go into a field that helps people" - then a PhD in Applied Maths is a huge distraction. Take up medicine or engineering.

Comment: @little True, I forgot the subject text exists

Answer (score 25):

To know whether you can do an applied math PhD, the question to ask is: did you succeed in difficult math, science, and computer science courses in undergrad, and do you have professors in relevant fields willing to write you a strong recommendation? General aptitude tests are dramatically less informative. This is not to say that, if you’re correct that you have average quantitative reasoning ability, a math PhD might not be the wrong choice for you. It’s just that you have other, much more refined and relevant, information available to judge by.

**EDIT:** Based on your edits, I’d say an A in Calc III at Columbia is more informative than the IQ test. That said, you have few advanced courses-only one, once you finish real analysis. So there’s not much evidence yet of your prospects. You’re in a plausible position to apply to master’s programs, and if you get into a good one, you’ll a get a much clearer idea of yourself there.

Comment: *General aptitude tests are dramatically less informative* --- Especially since we are given no information about the test. Also, the comment under the answer by @Allure doesn't really help much. What age are you, what is your math background, how well did you do in various math courses, etc.? For example, among other such things, saying something like "one of the top 3 students in a class of 28 students taking an honors level course in beginning calculus using Spivak's book at an Ivy League school" would be an example of what might be specific enough to begin trying to answer your question.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I refined the question.

Answer (score 9):

Looking at [example questions](https://gre.graduateshotline.com/quantitative_reasoning_test.html) in the quantitative reasoning section of the GRE, the questions are genuinely easy, and I would expect good high school students to be able to do well. A math PhD student scoring in the 63rd percentile is therefore very strange.

I've never worked in math PhD admissions, but my reactions would be 1) why did you do so poorly? (63rd percentile is not poor in general, but for a math PhD student it appears to be very poor), and 2) are you sure you have the background to study math at PhD level? Surely a math PhD student should have no problems solving the linear equation 3x-2 = 2x+5 for x - in fact, I'd expect a math PhD student to be able to solve quadratic equations easily. If the score genuinely reflects your ability, I would double check your transcript to see how much math you've done.

This doesn't mean that you cannot do a math PhD, but I'd make doubly sure that you do indeed have the basic skills needed to attempt it.

**Edit**: the question makes clear now that the scores weren't the GRE quantitative & verbal tests, but rather some kind of general IQ test. In that case it's a much, much weaker sign (if it is a sign at all) of inability to succeed at PhD level. If IQ implied mathematical ability, then it'd show up in your transcript, but it's the transcript that matters more than your IQ. If you score very well in your undergraduate courses, then what your IQ is is unimportant ... conversely, if your IQ is very high but you don't score well in your undergraduate courses, it would still be a red flag.

Comment: I believe the "63rd percentile" figure that the OP mentions is regarding the IQ test mentioned in the fifth paragraph, since they later say "[r]egarding the GRE, I expect I’d be able to score in a percentile on par with other prospective applicants", which implies they haven't taken the GRE yet.

Comment: Note that there is a big difference between the math section of the general GRE (which tests high school level math) and the specialized GRE math (which tests all the calculus sequence and a little more). Nevertheless there is a nontrivial proportion of pure math phds who score 100% perfect on the GRE math but this is by no means necessary and it is not true that the rest scores just slightly below that. A lot of math phds are very good at things tested in GRE math, some are not. Both can get very good and successful math phds.

Comment: @quarague I don’t think that’s very accurate. 167/170 is the average math GRE score for admitted MIT engineering PhD students; I think it is very close to true that “the rest score slightly below that” for top programs. I would say the math phds who aren’t very good-to the moderate standard of the GRE-at high school math are few and far between, and the majority of the latter could become very good by reviewing the boring basics for a few hours.

Comment: @KevinCarlson You are aware that MIT is one of the very top universities in the US? I could also image that engineering has a bigger emphasis on the GRE than pure math, because engineers need to actually calculate a lot more than mathematicians and that is essentially what the GRE math tests. Whether you are good at understanding and proving things is not part of the GRE math, a lot harder to test and a more important for a math phd than being able to calculate well.

Comment: @quarague If someone’s going for a PhD, I assume they’re going for the top programs. In pure math weaker programs have a rather poor career outlook. I suppose someone might get an applied PhD at a weaker program to qualify for a government or industry job, but my sense is that even outside of academia most PhD-level positions are so competitive that if one can’t get into a top program, it’s likely not worth it on career grounds-assuming that’s the basis of the decision, of course. In the same way, I advise people who can’t get into a top-14 law school not to go to law school.

Comment: @quarague The rest of your comment is fine, but the point is that the calculations on the general GRE are very easy. Math PhDs are almost always pretty good at all of math.

Comment: @KevinCarlson So you are advising that say 90% of all pure math phd students or law students actually made a bad career decision? That sounds a bit harsh.

Comment: @quarague I cannot speak for Math, but there is good evidence that at least the majority of Law students have made a poor decision.

Comment: @quarague Yes, I am, although I don’t know if I’d endorse the 90% number precisely. It may lessen the harshness that I don’t put all the blame on the students. Even in top math programs, the great majority of students do not go on to pure math careers.

Comment: @KevinCarlson well, I guess I would have to ask you to produce the data to support your claim.

Comment: @cdela There certainly exist people who outperform their department. In math, it’s very difficult to do research that speaks for itself in this way without being constantly exposed to the mathematicians who are doing leading research-everything is not in books. I don’t know anything about physics, but I would point out that your friend has apparently lived in three states and two continents over four consecutive temporary and underpaid positions-and indeed is probably outperforming most of her peers! If that’s what she wanted, more power to her, but many people find such a life unfulfilling.

Comment: @Cdela Which claim, precisely?

Comment: @mai the question's been edited since I wrote this answer - it was originally just the first two paragraphs, which I (incorrectly) assumed meant the GRE verbal & quantitative scores.

Comment: I'm surprised how many people in this thread seem to be unaware of how much universities are turning away from admissions testing these days.  Sure, they might hold in general cases regarding a specific type of student but it's become more and more widely recognized that they only measure a particular set of skills.  For instance: https://www.insidehighered.com/admissions/article/2019/10/07/brown-follows-princeton-letting-departments-make-choice-gre

Comment: @KevinCarlson We seem to have different opinions on how to measure a successful math phd. You said that only very few end up with a pure maths career, why I interpret as becoming a professor with some strong research focus. It is true that only very few succeed in that and that a phd from one of the strongest universities is the most viable path there. But you can also have a very satisfying career as a math lecturer at a liberal arts college or do some math heavy industry job. In both cases a math phd from a mid tier university will open job opportunities you wouldn't have without a phd.

Answer (score 9):

I certainly wouldn't give up hope. The reason is that "number" per se is a very small part of mathematics. Quantitative reasoning helps in many things, of course, but there are lots of areas where it is less important than, say logical reasoning and a geometric sense (among other things).

Mathematics is largely about abstraction and relationships, much more so than about "quantity". Most people get their feet wet in quantitative studies and Real Analysis is grounded in numeracy. But even Complex Analysis has many important results that are non-intuitive to a novice.

So, just assume that there are still large segments of both pure and applied math that you may be well suited for. I suggest you explore rather than give up.

---

Note: I have a doctorate in Mathematics. Real Analysis specialty but a strong interest and some accomplishment in Topology. Computer Science, which most of my career was involved with draws on the same ability of abstraction and composition. They aren't exactly the same, but intersect in many ways.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, I don't think anyone knows if "quantitative reasoning" WAIS subscores are indicative of talent in higher mathematics. It's possible that you would make a lousy accountant but a good mathematician. You probably already know whether you're "good with numbers," and you surely already know that what you do in advanced mathematics doesn't have a lot to do with what you're asked to do on a WAIS. It's unfortunate that even people who should know better tend to conflate quantitative or computational fluency with mathematical talent.

Speaking from my own experience, I reliably score around the 30th percentile for "arithmetic fluency," although there is nothing wrong with my ability to reason mathematically. But I'm not the person you should ask to do your taxes.

Secondly, ADHD often shows up as irregular profiles in skills and aptitude testing. Whatever the WAIS-III is worth, it needs to be interpreted carefully and in context. You can't really conclude much from a single subscore.

Answer (score 3):

I just want to point out one example, it is a somewhat of a common story but I couldn't find any decent sources. [Garry Kasparov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garry_Kasparov) is a titan of chess. He is one of the very bests if not the best. He had been the world champion for many years. Apperantly people used to estimate his IQ was between 180 and 190. He allegedly took an IQ test in the 80s and scored 135. Now, 135 is quite low considering his extreme success. Above 130 IQ seem to be estimated to be 2% of world population. Which might still sound high but there are billions of people.

Comment: IQ scores follow roughly a Gaussian distribution. There are roughly 17% above 115, 2% above 130 and 0.1% above 145. Anything above that is essentially just guesswork. These few lucky people are by now means all the same but the difference cannot be easily squeezed into a x point IQ difference. Estimating the IQ of anyone at 180 or 190 just shows that whoever did the estimate has no clue what these numbers mean. The fact that Kasparov plays better chess than any other random grand master does not imply that he has a higher IQ.

Comment: @JohnDoucette wut? The abstract says the disparity between 20 and 70 is "as much as 2.3" sd, "at least 85%" of which is due to the Flynn effect. Since 1 sd = 15 points, that would mean any decline is at most 0.34 sd = 5 points. All of which is irrelevant anyway, since the post says Kasparov supposedly took the test in **the** 80s, not **his** 80s. I think Kasparov is in his 50s.

Comment: @JohnDoucette, again dubious sources claim the test was taken in 87 or 88, Kasparov would 24 or 25 years old at that time. He became a world champion in 85 at the age of 22.

Comment: @BoatyMcboatface Ah, I misunderstood, and thought this was in _his_ 80's, not the 1980's. I'll remove my comments.

Answer (score 2):

> As someone who has a relative deficit in quantitive reasoning vs. verbal, but a strong interest in applied math, is it possible to be successful and competitive at the PhD level?

You could succeed in fields like [topological algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_algebra) or [mathematical logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_logic).

> I'm specifically interested in applied math.

Consider also [computer science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_science). You should view it as some applied mathematics. Look into [π-calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A0-calculus) for a good example. And the job opportunities could be better (e.g. around [artificial intelligence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_intelligence), [semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics_(computer_science)), [static program analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_program_analysis), [machine learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning), [cybersecurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_security), etc...). See [these slides on *the future of mathematics*](http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~buzzard/one_off_lectures/msr.pdf).

Consider also [computer programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_programming) and [software development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_development). It is [tightly](http://bootstrappingartificialintelligence.fr/WordPress3/) related to math, and I tend to believe you'll need some of it during your math PhD.  I know several persons ([Roberto Di Cosmo](http://www.dicosmo.org/), [Xavier Leroy](https://xavierleroy.org/), or [Roberto Bagnara](http://www.cs.unipr.it/~bagnara/), or the late [Jacques Pitrat](http://bootstrappingartificialintelligence.fr/WordPress3/), or [Emmanuel Haucourt](http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/Labo/Emmanuel.Haucourt/publications--preacutesentations.html) to name a few) who had an exceptional academic career while being expert in both math and programming.

Look also into [economics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economics), [bioinformatics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bioinformatics), [computational chemistry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_chemistry), and [theoretical physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theoretical_physics) (as science with a lot of math, so much that you might view them as applied math).

PS. [I got](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/cv-Basile-Starynkevitch.pdf) a PhD in 1990 but not in math, just in AI. I am French, so your GRE things make no sense at all for me. In France, some equivalent could be the [baccalauréat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baccalaur%C3%A9at). I graduated from [ENS Cachan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89cole_normale_sup%C3%A9rieure_Paris-Saclay) which probably has no real US equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

I would say with quite strong confidence that the score on a test is insufficient to determine your ability in such a vast field as maths.

Consider the following:

- All tests are imperfect. Some very intelligent people score badly and some very "average" people score highly
- A single sub-test bares little resemblance to most you will be doing in a PhD. E.g. reading papers, communicating with colleagues, writing eloquently, researching questions, doing formal maths, programming, etc. I would particularly stress some underappreciated skills such as communicating with colleagues

I did a PhD in Applied Maths and spend most of my time in a laboratory doing fluid dynamics experiments, setting up cameras, writing code to do image analysis, build experimental apparatuses etc.

Finally, I have done quite a bit of maths at University and I found that maths doesn't come easily. In my first semester as a under-grad I was studying for my first exam and read all the lecture notes, attempted all the examples and understood zero. At that point I was a little bit panicking. Next day, I came back and tried it all again. Again, I felt I understood nothing. Not knowing what else to do, seriously worried, I came back on the third day. Finally I understood a little bit. On the fourth day, suddenly everything fell into place in a couple of hours. I've repeated this experience for every lecture course. A period of incomphresnshion that eventually gives way to understand by repeatatly reading the same notes an examples.

This is of course a personal story and your experience will vary but I think determination can go a long way, particularly in a field like math.